The template code is not able to compile
The solochain template code is not compiling today. previously it was working as expected but today the same code is giving below issue.
  --> /Users/pankaj/.cargo/git/checkouts/polkadot-sdk-cff69157b985ed76/3649614/substrate/client/rpc-servers/src/middleware/rate_limit.rs:43:76
   |
43 |             inner: Arc::new(RateLimitInner::direct_with_clock(Quota::per_minute(n), &clock)),
   |                             ---------------------------------                       ^^^^^^ expected `QuantaClock`, found `&QuantaClock`
   |                             |
   |                             arguments to this function are incorrect
   |
note: associated function defined here
  --> /Users/pankaj/.cargo/registry/src/index.crates.io-6f17d22bba15001f/governor-0.6.4/src/state/direct.rs:58:12
   |
58 |     pub fn direct_with_clock(quota: Quota, clock: C) -> Self {
   |            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
help: consider removing the borrow
   |
43 -             inner: Arc::new(RateLimitInner::direct_with_clock(Quota::per_minute(n), &clock)),
43 +             inner: Arc::new(RateLimitInner::direct_with_clock(Quota::per_minute(n), clock)),
   |

For more information about this error, try `rustc --explain E0308`.
error: could not compile `sc-rpc-server` (lib) due to 1 previous error
warning: build failed, waiting for other jobs to finish...


Looks like the governor create is updated 2 days ago which is using by polkadot sdk so maybe because of that.
code repo: https://github.com/Polkaverse/solochain-template

Use below command to resolve above issue
cargo update -p governor:0.6.4 --precise 0.6.0

